# Getting "server certificate verification failed" during apt-get update

Tags: apt

I am trying to update a system using an HTTPS package mirror located here:

```
 https://mirror.ufs.ac.za/os/linux/distros/ubuntu/ubuntu/
```

However, during `apt-get update`, I get the following message:

```
Packages  server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none
```

If you visit the site in your browser, you are warned about the site's certificate, but I trust the site, so it's not an issue for me. I assume I must be able to add this exception somewhere for apt to proceed.

Can you tell me where and how?

Comment: Ignoring certificate validation errors isn't a matter of trusting the site. It means you're trusting anyone who can influence network traffic between yourself and that site - for example anyone you're trusting your wifi network and ISP.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

After reading up on the matter, following a trail about "self-signed certificates" etc., I found a suitable answer in a question on Serverfault: https://serverfault.com/questions/340887/using-a-self-signed-ssl-cert-for-an-https-based-internal-apt-repository

By adding the following line to my `apt.conf`, it resolved the matter:

```
Acquire::https::mirror.ufs.ac.za::Verify-Peer "false";
```

But keep in mind, that "resolved" means, that it might "work" now. Disabling verification is rather a workaround.

Comment: It can also be used directly in the command line with the `-o` parameter: `apt-get update -o Acquire::https::mirror.ufs.ac.za::Verify-Peer=false`

Comment: This worked for me whereas Answer [1095266](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1095266/apt-get-update-failed-because-certificate-verification-failed-because-handshake) that says `[trusted yes]` is needed did not.

Comment: I don't have a `apt.conf` on my ubuntu 16.04, so this does not work for me.

Comment: In my experience, you have to add `[trusted yes]`, in fact, only using `[trusted yes]` works without `Acquire::https::mirror.ufs.ac.za::Verify-Peer=false`