# apt-get update failed because certificate verification failed because handshake failed on nodesource

Tags: apt, 18.04, updates, ssl, nodejs

Running `sudo apt-get update` on my AWS EC2 Ubuntu 18.04.01 LTS instance fails:

```
Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate issuer is unknown
```

when trying to access the **deb.nodesource.com/node_10.x bionic Release**

Here is the result after running `sudo apt-get update`:

```
Hit:1 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Get:2 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]
Ign:3 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_10.x bionic InRelease
Get:4 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [74.6 kB]
Err:5 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_10.x bionic Release
  Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate issuer is unknown.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification. [IP: XX.XXX.XX.XX 443]
Get:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [83.2 kB]
Reading package lists... Done
W: https://deb.nodesource.com/node_10.x/dists/bionic/InRelease: No system certificates available. Try installing ca-certificates.
W: https://deb.nodesource.com/node_10.x/dists/bionic/Release: No system certificates available. Try installing ca-certificates.
E: The repository 'https://deb.nodesource.com/node_10.x bionic Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

It seems like my current installation of Node.js is causing the problem.

I have tried installing and updating `ca-certificates` in `etc/ssl/certs`, however, this did not help. I'm not exactly sure how to proceed from here to resolve this issue.

I'm not looking for a quick workaround that would compromise the security of the server.

Answer (score 117):

I experienced this error trying to add the keys for mongodb-org 4.0 to a docker container running Ubuntu 18.04. There was a problem with the certificates installed in this base image. I managed to fix it by install `ca-certificates`:

```
sudo apt install ca-certificates
```

Comment: Thanks - this actually solved the problem without bypassing security.

Comment: I'm on an infrequently used "Ubuntu for Windows" instance and I can't install ca-certificates because esm.ubuntu.com server certificate verification failed...

Comment: Mine says I'm already running the current version

Comment: @KatasticVoyage Then you may have a different issue. Could you post a new question with all the relevant details, and reference this question saying that these solutions didn't work for you? I reckon plenty has changed since these questions & answers.

Comment: This should be an accepted answer. Today met the same problem inside of 18.04.* container, installing `ca-certificates` resolved it. Thanks!

Comment: I think the reason this happens is because the root certificates on the Ubuntu are outdated, so upgrading ca-certificates solves it.

Comment: @lucaswxp Frankly speaking, I don't have the knowledge to know if what you said is the real cause of the problem, but I really appreciate that you are explaining "why" instead of simply doing "how".

Comment: For me, I just had to make sure I updated it... `sudo apt install --only-upgrade ca-certificates`

Comment: It fixed for my by update the already installed ca-certificates package with this above command.

Comment: This fixed my Sublime Text error! Nice. Here was my error: `Err:6 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ Release                                 
  Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate chain uses expired certificate.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification. [IP: 104.236.0.104 443]`...`E: The repository 'https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.`

Comment: Note: for my Sublime Text comment above [see their forum here](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/certificate-verification-failed/61064?u=ercaguy). They linked back to this answer. Upvoted!

Comment: it does nothing, same error

Answer (score 34):

You can add `[trusted=yes]` in the `sources.list`. For example:

```
deb [trusted=yes] http://ppa.launchpad.net/repo_name/pkg/ubuntu vivid main
deb-src [trusted=yes] http://ppa.launchpad.net/repo_name/pkg/ubuntu vivid main
```

Comment: Hi Mike. I'm still seeing the same error after updating both `/etc/apt/sources.list` and `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list` with `[trusted=yes]` as shown above.

Comment: sorry for the newbie question, but where is sources list, how do I add trusted=yes, and what does "vivid" mean in this context?

Comment: If you are VPNing through somewhere that uses ZScaler or something alike then you may hit this problem too. In my case I had only to turn off the vpn and the update went flawless.

Comment: @schlingel `sources.list.d` at `/etc/apt/`, `vivid` is the first part of Ubuntu release (version) name..

Comment: not work for me...

Answer (score 34):

For those still having this issue, here is a solution which I gleaned from the [Ubuntu manpages](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/apt-transport-https.1.html).

The OP's post indicates a certificate verification error:

```
Err:5 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_10.x bionic Release
Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate issuer is unknown.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification. [IP: XX.XXX.XX.XX 443]
```

I was having similar issues on a VM which sits behind a corporate proxy.  The proxy acts as a man-in-the-middle, decrypting and re-encrypting traffic as it flows through the proxy.  Even though I had the trusted certificate installed on my VM for the proxy, this error was still happening, caused by an invalid OCSP response.  To fix it, I ran this command:

```
touch /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99verify-peer.conf \
&& echo >>/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99verify-peer.conf "Acquire { https::Verify-Peer false }"
```

This disables apt's OCSP verification, and is not recommended.

I chose a different solution, which may not be available to others.  Our company maintains a non-decrypting proxy for use cases like this, so I switched to using it.

Comment: Thankyou in advance itworks

Comment: Yes, I had the same problem – it was because of company security settings.

Comment: NOT RECOMMENDED [security purpose] but it's still being a very great explanation

Answer (score 19):

Make sure your date and time are set correctly.

Comment: This fixed my issue on an old debian system.

Comment: This fixed the issue for me on Ubuntu 20, arm64

Comment: On this topic, for my devices having wrong time(s), connecting them to an NTP server fixed this problem.

Answer (score 7):

This happened today to me on an old, poorly maintained Ubuntu 16 release.

The first problem was that the sources in /etc/apt were HTTP and not HTTPS, and they had been blocked. The HTTPS links failed verification, which was expected since I believe they use LetsEncrypt and they changed their certification path last October.

But I could not update `ca-certificates` because they were believed current -- and I could not make apt understand they *weren't* current because, you know, the update was not working.

So:

1. Temporarily disable certificate verification by adding

   ```
   Acquire { https::Verify-Peer false }
   ```

   in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99verify-peer.conf`.
2. Run `apt update` to get the new ca-certificates info
3. Run `apt install ca-certificates`
4. Re-enable certificate verification

   Edit the file above and remove the peer-verification bypass. If the file is now empty, you may delete it.

Now everything should *mostly* work.

I then proceeded to clean the apt cache, and run a full dist-upgrade. This, in turn, unlocked the `do-release-upgrade` command. It did not work completely on the first time around, I had to run `apt-get update` again, clean unneeded packages and remove two packages that were conflicted, and update.

After a couple of hours and another release upgrade from 18, I got the system running Ubuntu 20.04-LTS and could reinstall the two missing packages from the previous stage. Everything is okay now.

Answer (score 5):

You can replace `https://` with `http://` from setup script using sed.

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sed 's|https://|http://|' | sudo -E bash -
```

This should be used as the last alternative of course.

Comment: Welp... not recommended... Also, some resources may redirect to HTTP over SSL/TLS anyways on their back-end.

Comment: Thanks that worked for me to change https to http, install `apt install ca-certificates` and again change http to https. https://serverfault.com/questions/1093511/apt-get-update-failing-because-of-certificate-validation/1133024#1133024

Answer (score 2):

**What caused the problem**

I was originally trying to install Node.js on Ubuntu 18.04.01 LTS via PPA and curl via:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x -o nodesource_setup.sh
```

However, running this command generated a `nodesource.list` file in `etc/apt/sources.list.d/` with the following contents:

```
deb https://deb.nodesource.com/node_10.x xenial main
deb-src https://deb.nodesource.com/node_10.x xenial main
```

So when running `sudo apt update` these sources could not be trusted via SSL handshake which caused to the update to fail.

**How I fixed it**

1. Navigated to `/etc/apt/nodesource.list.d`
2. Removed `nodesource.list` file from the system with

   `sudo rm nodesource.list`
3. Purged the system of any current Node.js installation with

   `sudo apt-get purge nodejs`

   `sudo apt-get autoremove`
4. Installed the Distro-Stable Version of Node.js for Ubuntu with:

   `sudo apt update`

   `sudo apt install nodejs`

   `sudo apt install npm`

Comment: "So when running ... these sources could not be trusted via SSL handshake": Why could they not be trusted?

Comment: @BlenderBender At the time this error happened, I couldn't find the root cause as to why these sources could not be trusted.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same error on WSL2 Ubuntu and tried to install `ca-certificates` with no luck, as it was already installed.

Then I updated `/etc/apt/sources.list` to use the global servers, updated Apt, and now it works. After upgrading, I saw some updates were made in the `/etc/ssl/certs` directory; new certificates.

Out of curiosity, I changed `sources.list` file to use the mirror servers again, and everything works.

Comment: can you tell me the global servers and how did you updated /etc/apt/source.list file?

Answer (score 2):

This error can be caused by not having the certs in `/etc/ssl/certs` world-readable.  I ran into this after restoring my certs from a backup: for me, the `/etc/ssl` directory itself was set to `750` instead of `755` making it's contents unreadable except to root.

Try these commands if you're having trouble and reinstalling `ca-certificates` doesn't help:

```
sudo chmod 755 /etc /etc/ssl /etc/ssl/certs
sudo chmod 644 /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

Comment: And you're exactly right, sir! Kudos for posting. Was super-puzzled by seeing the relevant CA roots present in the ca bundle, browser/`curl`/`openssl s_client` verifying no problem — but `apt` acting up. Turned out, a cert issuing script I used before on this machine, set /etc/ss/certs to 750. Best wishes

Comment: This solved my problem!

Answer (score 2):

To summary all the response above, there are 3 possibilities:

1/ ca-certificates are not installed
Solution:

```
apt install -y ca-certificates
```

But you say they are. So for you, that should not be an answer.

2/ disable https check (https::Verify-Peer)
Solution: add this to /etc/apt/conf.d/

```
Acquire { https::Verify-Peer false }
```

but that reduce your security.

3/ find the certificate of your server and add it

Comment: This adds no value

Answer (score 2):

This fixed it for me:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata
sudo date -s "$(wget -qSO- --max-redirect=0 google.com 2>&1 | grep Date: | cut -d' ' -f5-8)Z"
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade ca-certificates --fix-missing
```

Credits to:

- https://askubuntu.com/a/683136/22776
- https://askubuntu.com/a/81300/22776

Answer (score 1):

This issue can also occur due to corrupt cache.
I resolved this by:

```
sudo apt clean
```

then

```
sudo apt update
```

then

```
sudo apt upgrade
```

Comment: thanks, this helped

Answer (score 1):

I meet same problem,
here fix (try) step by step.

// base on `caffeinated.tech`'s answer,
//   I guess something break my `ca-certificates` package.

### 1. mirror 1

```
sudo apt-get update
Ign:1 https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/ubuntu focal InRelease
Ign:2 https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                     
Ign:4 https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease                                               
Ign:5 https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/ubuntu focal-security InRelease                                                 
Ign:6 https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/ubuntu focal-proposed InRelease           
Hit:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jgmath2000/et/ubuntu focal InRelease
Err:8 https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/ubuntu focal Release
  Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate chain uses expired certificate.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification. [IP: 218.104.71.170 443]
Err:9 https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/ubuntu focal-updates Release
  Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate chain uses expired certificate.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification. [IP: 218.104.71.170 443]
Err:10 https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/ubuntu focal-backports Release                                       
  Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate chain uses expired certificate.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification. [IP: 218.104.71.170 443]
Err:11 https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/ubuntu focal-security Release                                        
  Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate chain uses expired certificate.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification. [IP: 218.104.71.170 443]
Err:12 https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/ubuntu focal-proposed Release
  Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate chain uses expired certificate.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification. [IP: 218.104.71.170 443]
Hit:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/libretro/stable/ubuntu focal InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/ubuntu focal Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/ubuntu focal-updates Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/ubuntu focal-backports Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/ubuntu focal-security Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/ubuntu focal-proposed Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

### 2. mirror 2

```
 sudo apt-get update
Ign:1 https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/ubuntu focal InRelease
Ign:2 https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease        
Ign:3 https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease      
Ign:4 https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/ubuntu focal-security InRelease       
Err:5 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
  Something wicked happened resolving 'dl.google.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err:6 https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/ubuntu focal Release                    
  Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate chain uses expired certificate.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification. [IP: 101.6.15.130 443]
Hit:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jgmath2000/et/ubuntu focal InRelease                
Err:8 https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/ubuntu focal-updates Release
  Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate chain uses expired certificate.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification. [IP: 101.6.15.130 443]
Err:9 https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/ubuntu focal-backports Release
  Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate chain uses expired certificate.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification. [IP: 101.6.15.130 443]
Err:10 https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/ubuntu focal-security Release                                      
  Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate chain uses expired certificate.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification. [IP: 101.6.15.130 443]
Hit:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/libretro/stable/ubuntu focal InRelease                                         
Reading package lists... Done                                
E: The repository 'https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/ubuntu focal-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/ubuntu focal-backports Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/ubuntu focal-security Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

### 3. offical

```
sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease                                                                                           
Hit:3 http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease           
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jgmath2000/et/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:5 http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease        
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/libretro/stable/ubuntu focal InRelease    
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
39 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
```

### 4. install ca-certificates

```
sudo apt install ca-certificates 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gir1.2-evince-3.0 libllvm11 libmusicbrainz5-2 linux-headers-5.8.0-43-generic linux-hwe-5.8-headers-5.8.0-43 linux-image-5.8.0-43-generic linux-modules-5.8.0-43-generic
  linux-modules-extra-5.8.0-43-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be upgraded:
  ca-certificates
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 39 not upgraded.
Need to get 145 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,024 B disk space will be freed.
Get:1 http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 ca-certificates all 20210119~20.04.2 [145 kB]
Fetched 145 kB in 2s (87.6 kB/s)          
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 363632 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../ca-certificates_20210119~20.04.2_all.deb ...
Unpacking ca-certificates (20210119~20.04.2) over (20210119~20.04.1) ...
Setting up ca-certificates (20210119~20.04.2) ...
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
0 added, 1 removed; done.
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
Processing triggers for ca-certificates (20210119~20.04.2) ...
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
0 added, 0 removed; done.
Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d...
done.
```

// here found ca-certificates upgraded,
// which was not found before (maybe something break old package)

### 5. mirror 1, again

```
sudo apt update
Hit:1 https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:3 https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
Hit:4 https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
Hit:5 https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
Hit:6 https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/ubuntu focal-proposed InRelease
Hit:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jgmath2000/et/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/libretro/stable/ubuntu focal InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
55 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
```

this time it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered a problem that is similar to yours, with the Ubuntu Server installed in a VM, but the underlying cause should be different. I put out the problem description and the solution in case that someone who encountered the same problem reaches here.

**Brief Summary**:
The similar problem is caused by the network condition of our office. When the problem occurs, I used a bridged network for Internet access. After changing the VM network setting to the normal NAT, the problem is mitigated.

**Background**:
I have installed `Ubuntu Server LTS 18.04.3` with *VMWare Player*. After the installation is completed, I have used the VM for several days, including upgrading the system with `sudo apt update|upgrade` and install new applications with `sudo apt install <appname>`.

**Problem**:
After a weekend, I reopen the VM and want to install some new software. So I first try to update the repository information with `sudo apt update` to see if there are something that is upgradable. However, after executing this command, I get the following results:

```
gary@ubuntu-vm:~$ sudo apt update
Ign:1 https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Ign:2 https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
Ign:3 https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
Ign:4 https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
Err:5 https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/ubuntu bionic Release
  Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate issuer is unknown.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification. [IP: 101.6.8.193 443]
Err:6 https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/ubuntu bionic-updates Release
  Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate issuer is unknown.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification. [IP: 101.6.8.193 443]
Err:7 https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/ubuntu bionic-backports Release
  Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate issuer is unknown.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification. [IP: 101.6.8.193 443]
Err:8 https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/ubuntu bionic-security Release
  Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate issuer is unknown.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification. [IP: 101.6.8.193 443]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/ubuntu bionic Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/ubuntu bionic-updates Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/ubuntu bionic-backports Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/ubuntu bionic-security Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

which is similar to the [aseked problem](https://askubuntu.com/q/1095266/822680)(e.g., `Ign:3` and `Err:5`), but not the same.

**Solution**:
I have searched the related topics on Google, and many said that the problem is caused by incorrect configuration of certificates. However, I should never change any certificate configuration after installation of the system. Besides, avoiding certificates authentication should not be a regular routine.

To make sure that I did not change related configurations, I reinstall the system. I found that the installation cannot be completed, with the error log similar to the above one. After finding this, I guess that this problem should be caused by the network connection problem, as in this point there is no configuration made to the system.

Therefore, I checked the configuration of the VM instance, and found that this VM uses a bridged network rather than NAT. So I changed the network setting to NAT, which is usually the default network setting, then everything returns to normal!

After that, I recalled that when I first install the VM, I connect my computer to another computer to share the network (using NAT at the second computer). Later, I have my own network connection and I want the VM direct access to the physical network, so I changed the VM network setting to a bridged network, which then caused the problem (**It's simply a network connection problem, because the physical network require authentication for network connection, while the VM does not have the credentials**).

Answer (score 0):

touch /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99verify-peer.conf 
&& echo >>/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99verify-peer.conf "Acquire { https::Verify-Peer false }"

Will disable Cert verification, and no error will be generated.

Answer (score 0):

**Try and update the GNU TLS-related packages.**
I had the same problem with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and the sublimetext APT repository, among others:

```
server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none
```

I had tried all the proposed solutions to no avail.
The funny thing is that if I ran `echo "" | gnutls-cli download.sublimetext.com -p 443` from another computer, the certificate was accepted, so I know it had to be a client problem.
Then, almost by chance, I checked the pending updates in Software Updater and there were two GNU TLS packages.
I updated them and magically all the errors disappeared.
I don't remember the package names exactly but here are all the TLS libaries installed on my machine:

```
ii  gnutls-bin                        3.4.10-4ubuntu1.9     amd64                 GNU TLS library - commandline utilities
ii  libcurl3-gnutls:amd64             7.47.0-1ubuntu2.19    amd64                 easy-to-use client-side URL transfer library (GnuTLS flavour)
ii  libgnutls-dev:amd64               3.4.10-4ubuntu1.9     amd64                 GNU TLS library - development files
ii  libgnutls-openssl27:amd64         3.4.10-4ubuntu1.9     amd64                 GNU TLS library - OpenSSL wrapper
ii  libgnutls28-dev:amd64             3.4.10-4ubuntu1.9     amd64                 dummy transitional package for GNU TLS library - development files
ii  libgnutls30:amd64                 3.4.10-4ubuntu1.9     amd64                 GNU TLS library - main runtime library
ii  libgnutlsxx28:amd64               3.4.10-4ubuntu1.9     amd64                 GNU TLS library - C++ runtime library
ii  libneon27-gnutls:amd64            0.30.1-3build1        amd64                 HTTP and WebDAV client library (GnuTLS enabled)
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer points apt-get at a custom cert store by using a config file and setting the APT_CONFIG environment variable to point at this new file.

```
echo 'Acquire::https {\
        CaInfo "/cacert.pem";\
}' > /apt.conf
APT_CONFIG=/apt.conf
```

Answer (score -2):

In my case, I moved to nvm installation steps... as the third party instance was not able to resolve this error, and I did not have sudo rights and other permissions in brief.

referred this URL for nvm steps ... https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-node-js-on-ubuntu-18.04/

Answer (score -2):

Err:14 https://apt.llvm.org/bionic llvm-toolchain-bionic-11 Release
Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The revocation or OCSP data are old and have been superseded.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification.

Time zone and date in ubuntu was configured manually. Browser was set to sync with ubuntu. This caused the error **The revocation or OCSP data are old and have been superseded**
Set time and date to auto update. Works fine

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.