# How to install Docker Ubuntu 18.04 with https proxy error

Tags: 18.04, proxy, docker, ssl

I have an issue of installing **Docker** on **ubuntu 18.04**

When I try the following lines I get an https error due to there being no http version and we are behind a company **proxy** so it fails.

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic stable"

sudo apt update
```

Fails with.

```
Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate issuer is unknown.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification.
```

Is there an alternative way to install even for a one of version using curl or wget?

Is there a way of bypassing a proxy in the apt conf to tell it to ignore the certificate error?

Edit 
I tried with the [trusted=yes] flag but this didn't work I think because this reverts to http and there is no http URL.

```
Err:6 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic Release                                        
Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate issuer is unknown.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification.
E: The repository 'https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [apt-get update failed because certificate verification failed because handshake failed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1095266/apt-get-update-failed-because-certificate-verification-failed-because-handshake). You may find this answer helpful: https://askubuntu.com/a/1095269/19626

Comment: Thanks, but the  [trusted=yes] didn't work i think this was because of the no http.

Comment: A blocked https *should* be a different error, and [trusted=yes] should prevent certificate verification errors, so this seems unusual.

Comment: Contact your network administrator, and get a copy of the CA certificate used by the proxy server. This will save you a lot of problems further down the road.

Answer (score 0):

From [docker's site](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/) here are the steps to install docker:

Update apt package index

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Install the requirements for docker

```
sudo apt-get install \
    apt-transport-https \
    ca-certificates \
    curl \
    gnupg-agent \
    software-properties-common
```

Add Docker's GPG key

```
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
```

Note: You should check the key if it's correct. (Follow the link)

Add Docker's repository

```
sudo add-apt-repository \
   "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
   $(lsb_release -cs) \
   stable"
```

Then update with apt

```
sudo apt-get update
```

And now you can install docker with apt

```
sudo apt-get install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io
```

Comment: Many thanks for the quick response this was what I was following, unfortunately when the step to add Dockers repository I will still get the same https error.  this is beacuse there is not http version and the company proxy won't validate the https . Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate issuer is unknown.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification