# install docker on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, docker

I've created an Ubuntu 18.04 VM, and I want to install docker on it.  I'm following the instructions at https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/ .

I'm having trouble at this step:

```
# sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) stable"
Hit:1 http://ubuntumirror.it.att.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://ubuntumirror.it.att.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://ubuntumirror.it.att.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
Ign:4 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Err:5 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic Release
  Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate issuer is unknown.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification. [IP: 135.28.13.29 8080]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

What should I do at this point?

Comment: Does this help?  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1095266/apt-get-update-failed-because-certificate-verification-failed-because-handshake, and also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54901780/error-by-trying-installing-docker-repository-on-linux-ubuntu-18-04-lts

Comment: Does this answer your question? [apt-get update failed because certificate verification failed because handshake failed on nodesource](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1095266/apt-get-update-failed-because-certificate-verification-failed-because-handshake)

Comment: Try installing `ca-certificates`:  `sudo apt-get install ca-certificates`.

Comment: The only solution out of this that seemed reliable was installing ca-certificates, and that was already latest.  However, something I did up to this point must have changed something, because when I just tried to run docker, it said I just had to installer "docker.io", which it didn't say before I started to go through the steps. In any case, it's now installed. Thanks for commenting.