# Exact commands to replace deprecated `add-apt-repository ppa:<username>/<package>` with gpg, curl, etc

Tags: apt, package-management, ppa, repository, gnupg

I understand that [`add-apt-repository` is being deprecated](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-handle-apt-key-and-add-apt-repository-deprecation-using-gpg-to-add-external-repositories-on-ubuntu-22-04) because it adds the repo key globally instead of specifically for the package(s) that need it.  However, the examples I see on the web don't show how to handle `ppa:<username>/<package>`

I can see [What commands (exactly) should replace the deprecated apt-key?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1286545/what-commands-exactly-should-replace-the-deprecated-apt-key) but I never used apt-key and the example doesn't show how to deal with the ppa part.

Here are the now-obsolete commands (openconnect requires vpnc which I think is hosted under the same ppa?):

```
apt update

apt install software-properties-common

add-apt-repository ppa:dwmw2/openconnect

apt install vpnc

apt install openconnect
```

If I could just unpack `ppa:dwmw2/openconnect` to separately download the key and add the repo, I could follow existing instructions for replacing `apt-key` and `apt-add-repository` separately and have a recipe for doing this for all other repository adds.

### Sub-question

Does `add-apt-repository` do this by screen-scraping from [https://launchpad.net/~dwmw2/+archive/ubuntu/openconnect](https://launchpad.net/%7Edwmw2/+archive/ubuntu/openconnect)?

No.  I'm still missing the key block because when I do:

```
curl -fsSL https://artifacts.elastic.co/GPG-KEY-elasticsearch
-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
Version: GnuPG v2.0.14 (GNU/Linux)
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=92oX
-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
```

That format looks nothing like

```
Signing key:
4096R/DBBE5FF954B458D1A0875E8A9FCCDFFB8838752F
Fingerprint:
DBBE5FF954B458D1A0875E8A9FCCDFFB8838752F
```

And `gpg --dearmor` produces binary output:
[image: dearmored elastasearch gpg key]

Hah!  I think I found at least part of the answer here:
https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA/InstallingSoftware#On_older_.28pre_9.10.29_Ubuntu_systems

Now:

```
# apt update
...

# apt install gpg
...

# gpg --homedir /tmp --no-default-keyring --keyring /usr/share/keyrings/openconnect.gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys DBBE5FF954B458D1A0875E8A9FCCDFFB8838752F
gpg: keybox '/usr/share/keyrings/openconnect.gpg' created
gpg: /tmp/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key 9FCCDFFB8838752F: public key "Launchpad PPA for dwmw2" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1

# echo 'deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/openconnect.gpg] https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/dwmw2/openconnect/ubuntu bionic main' >/etc/apt/sources.list.d/openconnect.list

# apt update
Hit:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                      
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease                                              
Ign:4 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/dwmw2/openconnect/ubuntu bionic InRelease                            
Hit:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease                                           
Err:6 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/dwmw2/openconnect/ubuntu bionic Release         
  Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate issuer is unknown.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification. [IP: 185.125.190.52 443]
Reading package lists... Done                              
W: https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/dwmw2/openconnect/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease: No system certificates available. Try installing ca-certificates.
W: https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/dwmw2/openconnect/ubuntu/dists/bionic/Release: No system certificates available. Try installing ca-certificates.
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/dwmw2/openconnect/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Easily fixed with:
[apt-get update failed because certificate verification failed because handshake failed on nodesource](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1095266/apt-get-update-failed-because-certificate-verification-failed-because-handshake)

Now:

```
# apt update
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease                                                                 
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease                                             
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease                                           
Get:5 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/dwmw2/openconnect/ubuntu bionic InRelease [15.9 kB]                  
Get:6 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/dwmw2/openconnect/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages [1437 B]
Fetched 17.3 kB in 1s (14.5 kB/s)  
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
```

Comment: `add-apt-repository` is [a Python script](https://git.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-properties/tree/), and it uses [the Launchpad API](https://launchpad.net/+apidoc/1.0.html#archive). You can try the API to get the signing key.