Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted
Recently, I have been getting this warning each time I try running a system update on my machine:
Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The name in the certificate does not match the expected.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification. [IP: 13.107.246.63 443]
Fetched 3,590 B in 9s (380 B/s)                                                
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
4 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
W: Failed to fetch https://apt.packages.shiftkey.dev/ubuntu/dists/any/InRelease  Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The name in the certificate does not match the expected.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification. [IP: 13.107.246.63 443]
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

What could be causing this and how do I mitigate it?
The OS used is Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
OS type 64-bit
Gnome version 42.9
Windowing wayland

The OS used is Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1095266/apt-get-update-failed-because-certificate-verification-failed-because-handshake

you can try sudo apt reinstall ca-certificates, that should fix it. If not, try some of the other things from above
